# Error BXNUI0044E on Bluemix with Cloud Foundry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

When I try to run my ruby on rails app in Bluemix, it generates the follow error:

BXNUI0044E

What is this?

Thanks

Comment: The Bluemix docs list this error as meaning that information wasn't retrieved from the server because a problem occurred contacting Cloud Foundry, and suggest that you try again later, check Bluemix status to see if any services you are using are down, and if the problem persists, contact support. 

https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/messages/bxnui.html

If you want to determine whether the problem is in your app itself, please provide code and say more about what you are trying to do with the app.

Comment: I've seen this error occurring in non-English locales when using the old Bluemix console (console.ng.bluemix.net). This problem does not happen in the new console (new-console.ng.bluemix.net).